# Post through google app scripts

Tags: ajax, post, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to post from a HTML form to a Google sheet. I am currently just trying to write the code in the Google App script but an error states "Script function not found: doGet" and I cannot figure out what to do. My code is below:

```
    function myFunction() {
        var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
   var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = [];
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap the whole script in "myFunction()", if you remove that function with his corresponding bracket it should work just fine.

Remove this =>  function myFunction() {  --from the beginning.

And this => }  -- from the end.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `ContentService`

[Google Documentation - Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content)